# How to get base url of website in jinja2?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

PHP has `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as a reference to the base url of a website: e.g. `http://localhost:8080/`. I need to do the same in `jinja2`. I am using python 2.7 on app engine.

How do I get the base url of website in jinja2?

Comment: @bossylobster, I am using webapp2. As for your `What have you tried?` This is not an algorithmic or problem solving question. This is language construct/library/vocabulary. This is similar to me asking `How do you say Hello in Spanish` and have you ask me what have I tried. So besides searching the internet for results: nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In webapp2, you can get the host part of a request and pass it as argument in a jinja template as follows:

```
class YourHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    params = {'url':self.request.host}
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('your_template.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(params))
```

Comment: This is what I did. My guest is `self.request.host` is more accurate than `self.request.application_url`. But both turn out to be sufficient in my case. Still I am changing to yours. Thanks.

Comment: @ThanosMakris, I followed your answer here for my case to display image with absolute url, but it does not work because `request.host` does not include protocol such as `http://` or `https://`. How can I make `request.host` ? Thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun If you also want to have the protocol, you can do the following:
`params = {'url':self.request.host_url}`

Comment: @ThanosMakris that’s it I want! Thanks Thanos

Answer (score 6):

`webapp2` is based on `WebOb`. From their [docs](http://webob.org/)

> WebOb is a Python library that provides wrappers around the WSGI
>   request environment, and an object to help create WSGI responses. The
>   objects map much of the specified behavior of HTTP, including header
>   parsing, content negotiation and correct handling of conditional and
>   range requests.

Accessing the [application URL](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/#urls) is enabled by the `request` object in a handler and can be accessed via the attribute `application_url`:

```
import webapp2
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.write(self.request.application_url)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer because it includes the protocol as well as the host and port